# ¿Se puede hacer que una Window retorne un valor en WPF? c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mensajes

Lo que quiero es bastante simple.
Dada la siguiente ventana:

[image: admmens]

Quiero que al apretar el botón verde la ventana retorne `true`, y cuando aprete el boton rojo retorne `false`.
Voy a usar esta ventana para mensajes en los que el usuario tenga que confirmar algún procedimiento. Por ejemplo, si va a eliminar un cliente de la base de datos, mostraría esta ventana con el mensaje "¿Está seguro de eliminar el cliente?". Si apreta el botón verde elimino el cliente y si apreta el botón rojo, no hago nada. Todo en base al valor que debería devolver esta ventana.

A esta ventana la llamo de la siguiente manera:

```
MsjSistema mensaje = new MsjSistema("Este es un mensaje de prueba");
mensaje.ShowDialog();
```

Lo que quiero saber es si se puede hacer algo como esto:

```
MsjSistema mensaje = new MsjSistema("Este es un mensaje de prueba");
bool respuesta = mensaje.ShowDialog();
```

Y en base al valor de respuesta hago lo que tenga que hacer...

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontré la solución e hice un nuevo método que se llama `ShowDialogRespuesta()` en la ventana de `MsjSistema` de modo que la clase quedaría así:

```
public partial class MsjSistema : Window
{
    private bool rta = false;
    public MsjSistema(string mensaje)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblMensaje.Text = mensaje;
    }

    private void btnAceptar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rta = true;
        Close();
    }

    private void btnCerrar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rta = false;
        Close();
    }

    public bool ShowDialogRespuesta()
    {
        this.ShowDialog();
        return rta;
    }
}
```

Entonces al llamar a esta ventana lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
MsjSistema mensaje = new MsjSistema("Este es un mensaje de prueba");
bool? b = mensaje.ShowDialogRespuesta();
```

De esa forma, `b` tiene el valor que le asigno a `rta` según el botón que apretó el usuario.